# How can I set a non-existing object in an activity in android

Tags: android

I asked this before but I will try to be clear because this question was closed as duplicate

The question:

when I click mbutton2 I want toset the size of a non existing textview in the activity, (((textview wont exist unless I click the mbutton1))) , but my app crash when I click mbutton2 and the system says : null reference error.

```
//in Main class

TextView textview;


//creating the text view on button click
Button mbutton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
mbutton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
textview=new TextView(this);

//adding the view to the relativelayout
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
textview.setLayoutParams(params);

//making object for Relativelayout and add the view to activity
RelativeLayout relativel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
relative1.addView(textview);
}
});

//now here is the button which must set the size of this text view
Button mbutton2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
mbutton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
textview.setsize(20);

}
});
//And the error is when I click button 2 it says null object reference.
```

I know the cause of the problem , I want a clear solution please.

Comment: Why not adding null check `if(textview!=null){textview.setsize(20);}` because `textview` is null until `mbutton1` not pressed

Comment: @ChiragSavsani  I reasked the question please if you got an answer , help me.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK can I set the text size if the textview object is still not in the activity, because if the user wants to set the size of the text before he even add the text.

Comment: int size  = 0; on button2 click you can set it to 20 and whenever you are creating a new textview just check if(size >0 ) then put the textView.setSize(size); has it solved your question???

Comment: @HasanB.T: Yes store it in `SharedPreferences` and when TextView present get size from `SharedPreferences` and call setsize method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK how do i store textview in sharedpreferences, and what is shared preferences?

Comment: @HasanB.T: See [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this,

```
int size = 14; // 14 is the default textview text size;

Button mbutton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
mbutton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
    public void onClick(View view){
    textview=new TextView(this);

    //adding the view to the relativelayout
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
    (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );

    textview.setTextSize(size); //setting up textview size (default or changed)

    textview.setLayoutParams(params);

    //making object for Relativelayout and add the view to activity
    RelativeLayout relativel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
    relative1.addView(textview);
    }
});

Button mbutton2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
mbutton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
    public void onClick(View view){

        size = 20;  // textview text size you want to set
        if(textview != null){
            textview.setTextSize(size);
        }

    }
});
```

Anything that you have only declared and trying to use it before initializing should show nullPointerException.
Here,

```
TextView textview; //--- This is the declaration
```

if you click on button2 before button1, initialization does not happen because,

```
textview=new TextView(this); //--- this line is inside button1 click listener. So textview remains null.
```

In the above code,

```
    size = 20;  // textview text size you want to set
    if(textview != null){
        textview.setTextSize(size);
    }
```

this section saving the textview size for use while initializing if textview is not initialized as you want to do and if initialized then setting the value.

Comment: you are a genius that's all I can say.